# Can't find template installed by nuget in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019, antlr4

I want to install Antlr4 Console App template mentioned in [here](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrVSIX/blob/master/doc/building.md),and nuget console tell me that I install it sucessfully.

But I can't find this template in create new project menu.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn3mi.png)

And I try to install it again,but nuget tell me "The template "Antlr4 Console App" was created successfully."

Comment: Could you provide an English translation of the error message?

Comment: I don't include the Antlr template anymore in the Antlrvsix extension. This is because I don't want to support the old-style VS2019 templates. Instead, install NET5 through the VS2019 Installer. Then, from Cmd/Bash/Powershell, type "dotnet new -i Antlr4BuildTasks.Templates". To create an Antlr program, create a directory of the name of your choice, eg., "mkdir foo", "cd foo", then type "dotnet new antlr". Afterwards, to build and run the program, type "dotnet restore", "dotnet run".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VS IDE does not contain the **Antlr4 Console App template** automatically. And it is for dotnet cli project template automatically(using command line to create).

If you want to create Antlr4 Console App template for VS IDE, you should follow these steps:

**1)** open **CMD** as Administrator and then type this to create the template for dotnet cli:

```
dotnet new -i Antlr4BuildTasks.Templates::8.9.1
```

**then**,

```
cd xxxx(a default empty folder which for the created project by dotnet cli)
dotnet new antlr
```

**2)** open the created antlr project by VS IDE

[image]

**After that**, click VS top menu **Project**-->**Export Template**-->**Project Template**

[image]

Input the info like my description and then click **Finish**.

**3)** Close VS, copy the generated `Antlr4 Console App.zip` file into `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#`:

[image]

**4)** restart VS and click new project.

For newly added templates, VS search and location are not too accurate, so often the template is at the end of the search results,

[image]